How can I configure my emacs so I can program in java?
I installed Emacs recently, because I already had a good experience with Vim (another ide that gives the user freedom to modify the ide as the user wants) and as I am studying Java together with Elisp I was asked, is there any way I can configure it? my emacs to develop in java?
Some mode or configuration that I add to the init file...

I googled "tutorial configuring emacs for java programming" and got a bunch of hits: some video tutorials, discussions on r/emacs and Stack Overflow and regular tutorials. That should give you enough for a start.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Vim is not an IDE.

You can program in Java (or any other language) with a bare Emacs (people have been doing that for 40-50 years): no additional packages needed. You seem to want IDE features (which you don't specify), so I pointed you to how to google and find a bunch of videos and tutorials that might help. But the question is vague and (probably) too wide and open-ended for this forum. Try to narrow down the scope to a single, specific, question. And just to prevent misunderstanding, there is no single thing that you can add to your init file and turn Emacs into a "Java IDE".

You're right, I wasn't very clear in my question, however I managed to resolve it, and I thank you for your feedback.

I understand that you have just now started the journey ... Once you are comfortably settled you can use the following resources for proceeding ahead java resources on reddit.com/r/planetemacs.  Remember much of the links that show up in results will be too advanced for a beginner, so use the resources a ROADMAP of the way ahead.

@mxnt Thank you for your answer, I installed the lsp-java packages from my configuration file
